# Error updating data - TypeError: put () got multiple values ​for argument 'connection'

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with Firebase and Python, but I have a small error when I try to add this data to a specific user and it is generating the following error, thanks I hope you help me

`TypeError: put () got multiple values ​​for argument 'connection'`

````
def Newcompra(user,items):
    global PlayerDB,TiendaDB
    
    info = {
        "id": TiendaDB[items]["id"],
        "nombre": TiendaDB[items]["nombre"],
        "historia": TiendaDB[items]["historia"],
        "tipo": TiendaDB[items]["tipo"],
        "g_type": TiendaDB[items]["g_type"],
        "peso": TiendaDB[items]["peso"],
        "tier": TiendaDB[items]["tier"],
        "envolver": TiendaDB[items]["envolver"],
        "evento_item": TiendaDB[items]["evento_item"],
        "fabricable": TiendaDB[items]["fabricable"],
        "intercanbio": TiendaDB[items]["intercanbio"],
        "precio": TiendaDB[items]["precio"],
        "venta": TiendaDB[items]["venta"],
        "atributos": {
            "ataque": TiendaDB[items]["atributos"]["ataque"],
            "defensa": TiendaDB[items]["atributos"]["defensa"],
            "mana": TiendaDB[items]["atributos"]["mana"],
            "habilidad": TiendaDB[items]["atributos"]["habilidad"],
            "nivel": TiendaDB[items]["atributos"]["nivel"]
           
    }
}

    Fire.put("/players",user,"/bolso_arm",items,info)
return```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I think you are sending too many parameters to Fire.put

It is expecting:

```
(url, name, data, params, headers, connection)
```

In normal use, you will only want to use the first three parameters. I am guessing your variables `user` and `items` each contain a string. It looks to me that you are trying to write, to a path such as:

```
/players/some-user-name/bolso_arm
```

the following information:

```
{
    "some-key": info
}
```

I think you are aiming to achieve this database entry on Firebase:

```
/players/some-user-name/bolso_arm/some-key: {
    "id": "......",
    "nombre": "......",
    "historia": "......",
....
}
```

#### You should merge all the elements of the path, except the last one, into a single string for the first parameter

I think you want the first parameter, `path`, to be:

```
/players/some-user-name/bolso_arm/
```

Then the second, `name`, to be:

```
some-key
```

And finally the `data` to be:

```
{
    "id": "......",
    "nombre": "......",
    "historia": "......",
    ....
}
```

#### Proposed code

I have added a "/" after "players".

```
Fire.put("/players/"+user+"/bolso_arm",items,info)
```

Now there are only three parameters, and it should work. Let us know how you get on.